# How do find out MSOLAP.2 provider installed in my machine?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, olap

How do find out `MSOLAP.2` provider installed in my machine. Also, How can i test the same through C# code?

Any help or guidelines are greatly appreciated !!!